# How do I sort date components in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, date, nsdatecomponents

I want to group data by dates which has initial format of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` and display as `E, dd MMM`. I have managed to group them by the dates but failed to sort the dates in a descending order. How do I sort the date components after grouping in Dictionary?

**JSON Response**

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "userId": "test1",
            "transactionTime": "2019-06-20T14:01:00.253+08:00"
        },
        {
            "userId": "test2",
            "transactionTime": "2019-06-16T14:02:00.253+08:00"
        },
        {
            "userId": "test3",
            "transactionTime": "2019-06-12T14:01:00.253+08:00"
        },
        {
            "userId": "tes4",
            "transactionTime": "2019-06-17T14:02:00.253+08:00"
        },
    ]
}
```

**Grouping**

```
func convertToDateObj() -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        // Convert from initial date string to date object
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: self)!
        return dateObj
    }


// Group list by date
let groupedList = Dictionary(grouping: rawTransactionsList, by: { list -> DateComponents in
    let dateObj = list.transactionTime.convertToDateObj()
    let date = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month], from: (dateObj))
    return date
})

// QUESTION
// How do I sort the keys?
// groupList.keys.sorted(...)?

// Populate my list with grouped list
groupedList.keys.forEach { key in
    print("Group keys \(key)")
    let values = groupedList[key]
    groupedtransactionsList.append(values ?? [])
}
```

Comment: Why are you only grouping by the day and month, but not year? Same days of different years will go into the same group. Is this intentional?

Comment: Your dictionary will be keyed with `DateComponents`. You would be better off grouping by `Date`. Also, why do you need the `convertToDateObj` function to do the grouping? Your struct should already have a `Date` property, not the string. Do that conversion automatically when decoding the JSON.

Comment: @Sweeper, it was not intentional, I should consider the year as well but how do I sort the keys?
@rmaddy I understand that, if it was a `Date` format, how do I do the grouping and sorting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably also group by the year, otherwise the same day in different years will be in the same group:

```
let date = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: (dateObj))
```

One way to sort the keys is to convert the date components back into `Date`s, using `Calendar.current.date(from:)`:

```
let sortedList = groupedList.sorted {
    Calendar.current.date(from: $0.key) ?? Date.distantFuture <
        Calendar.current.date(from: $1.key) ?? Date.distantFuture
}

sortedList.forEach { key, values in
    print("Group keys \(key)")
    groupedtransactionsList.append(values ?? [])
}
```

Comment: sortedList do not have the member of `keys`, it should be `sortedList.forEach { ... }` and  `dateComponents([.day, .month, .year]`

Comment: @SamuelKith I meant just `sortedList.forEach`. Oops!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use a date string with format `yyyy-MM-dd` as dictionary key rather than date components. This string can be sorted.

```
let groupedList = Dictionary(grouping: rawTransactionsList, by: { list -> String in
    let dateObj = list.transactionTime.convertToDateObj()
    let comps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: dateObj)
    return String(format: "%ld-%.2ld-%.2ld", comps.year!, comps.month!, comps.day!)
})

groupedtransactionsList = groupedList.keys.sorted(by: >).map { groupedList[$0]! }
```